# Why the random experience levels?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience

---

- If you gain too many experience points (such as a trillion through
  commands), the experience bar will disappear altogether as well as
  your level on your HUD. This appears to occur around level 32,767
- The maximum XP that you can earn from the /xp command is
  2,147,483,647 levels The maximum experience level is 24,791 (With
  just /xp).
- The maximum glitchless experience level is 32,767 (With just /xp
  (#L)(Where /xp is the level and the L increases the person's level by that many levels)
- The highest level you can gain with /xp without overflowing is
  1,241,258 which results in 2,147,483,647 exp, which is the maximum
  value for the int data type, in Java, which is what is used to store
  the exp value.

Maybe it's just me, but these numbers seem to make no sense.  Absolutely none of these numbers are even or just ended in zeroes.  Why did they use these numbers that just seem random?

Comment: They do if you're a programmer.  And the explanation is right there, in the text you copied.

Comment: They all start with 1s. Infact there are only 1s in the numbers that you mentiont. Google binary numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in how numbers are stored in a computer. Binary. 2,147,483,647 is the top end of the integer range, since it corresponds to 011111111111etctimes32digits. 32,767 is the top end of the signed short range, which corresponds to 0111111111111111, where the first zero indicates its a positive number.

Comment: On the C-variation languages: 2,147,483,647 is int32.MaxValue, 32,767 is int16.MaxValue. These values essentially use 16/32 bits in your memory (they look just like uni explained it (111111etc)). Why they are unsigned is beyond me though (unsigned ints can't go below 0, but levels don't need to too, and the level amount would be doubled.

Comment: @ardaozkal Because it's easier to check `( curXp - requiredXp ) > 0` then to do `( curXp - requiredXp ) > 0 && ( curXp - requiredXp ) < curXp`, which would be required for unsigned values.